# Make not-inheritable class methods in php

Tags: php, inheritance, methods, children

I have a base class (DB) which is inherited by many other classes.
The problem is I don't want inherit the DB class methods.
But I want these to be public for the user.

I put them the 'final' keyword but this one only don't let the children to overwrite the methods.

```
<?php

/*
 * DB class for MySQL server
*/
abstract class DB {
    protected static $return        = 'fetch_assoc';
    protected static $db            = null;
    protected static $table_prefix;
    protected static $return_type   = array(
        'fetch_lazy'    => 1,
        'fetch_assoc'   => 2,
        'fetch_num'     => 3,
        'fetch_both'    => 4,
        'fetch_obj'     => 5,
        'fetch_bound'   => 6,
        'fetch_column'  => 7,
        'fetch_class'   => 8,
        'fetch_into'    => 9,
        'fetch_func'    => 10,
        'fetch_named'   => 11
    );

    final static function connect (string $db_key) {
        ...
    }

    final static function beginTransaction () {
        ...
    }

    final static function rollback () {
        ...
    }

    final static function commit () {
        ...
    }

    final static function close () {
        ...
    }
}
```

So. I want the children to can see DB variables, but I want my methods to can be used only by the user.
How to make my methods non-inheritable because I don't want children see them?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? If the "user" instantiates one of the child classes, if the child class couldn't see the methods, the user wouldn't be able to call them.

Comment: This does not sound as if inheritance was the tool for your job. Maybe try composition?

Comment: Maybe you want to move the methods into a different class altogether. Then, that class could take the children of this class as a parameter.